# I am Using Maven for storm. Can I create a storm archtype ?

Tags: maven, apache-storm

What is the number we should enter for using storm with maven during running this command ?

```
mvn archtype:generate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactive generation allows you to apply filter in format `[groupId:]artifactId` while choosing archetype. 
I have tried to apply filter 'storm', but found nothing.